# Javascript export Error in render

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to export a **js** file into a **Vue** file using **exports** and **import**.

But the console keep saying the import is not **defined**.

I have tried putting everything inside the **vue** instance in **data()** and it **worked**, so this should be a import export problem

**code:**

icon.js

```
    var featherIcons = () => { return {
        "activity": "<polyline points='22 12 18 12 15 21 9 3 6 12 2 12'></polyline>", 
        "airplay": "<path d='M5 17H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h16a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-1'></path><polygon points='12 15 17 21 7 21 12 15'></polygon>" 
    } } 
    export { featherIcons };
```

index.vue

```
import { featherIcons } from './icons.js'

var featherIcons = featherIcons()

<template>
  <svg version="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    :width="width"
    :height="height"
    :viewBox="box"
    v-html="icon">
  </svg>
</template>
<script>
  module.exports = {
    name: 'feather-icon',
    props: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      },
      box: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: '0 0 24 24'
      },
      height: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: 24
      },
      width: {
        type: [Number, String],
        default: 24
      }
    },
    computed: {
      icon() {
        return this.feather(this.type)
      }
    },
    methods: {
      feather(icon) {
        return featherIcons[icon]
      }
    } 
  }
 </script>
```

Console error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: featherIcons is not defined"

found in

---> <FeatherIcon> at node_modules/vue-feather-icon/components/index.vue
```

Comment: try to remove`var featherIcons = () => { return {"` the last `"`

Comment: Sorry, that was an error while typing this question. My actual code does not have the extra "

Comment: `import { featherIcons } = './icons.js'` change `=` to `from`

Comment: it was definitely an error, wasn't  the cause tho :'(

Comment: ```import { featherIcons } from './icons.js'

var featherIcons = featherIcons()```should be in the `script`

Comment: Thank you so much!!  That fixed it. Adding on to this, I also should have used *require* instead of *import*

Comment: Rebinding an identifier bound to an import is invalid per the spec and is only working because you are transpiling and your transpiler is allowing sloppy code. It will break sooner or later so use a different name.

Comment: Yea, at that point I was trying anything possible to fix the error. The export was actually supposed to be an object, changed it to a function to see if that was the issue as a temporary trial and error. Thanks for the advice!